# Select all elements into a div with css

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select all elements into a div, so when I put the mouse outside do something.
Selecting directly the div's id is not working properly. There are some way to select an element and all their child?

```
$("...").mouseout(function(){

});
```

I have a div and other div into it that appear on mouse over, but when I try to hide it after appear with mouse out of it and leave the father div, the div is still there.

I tryed something like:

```
$(".release").mouseover(function(e){
    var selected_row = $(this).attr('id');
    var request_id = $(this).attr('id').slice(8);

    var position_top = $('#'+selected_row).offset().top;
    var position_left = $('#'+selected_row).offset().left;

    jQuery("#request_notes").css( "display", "inline" );
    jQuery("#request_notes").css( "position", "absolute" );
    jQuery("#request_notes").css( "top", position_top );
    jQuery("#request_notes").css( "left", mouse_left );

});

$("#request_notes").mouseout(function(){
    jQuery("#request_notes").css( "display", "none" );
});
```

When I do mouse out of the father div, the one that appear is still there. So I would like to do mouse out, of the father and his child.

http://jsfiddle.net/sebasparola/vRqH4/6/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("#request_notes").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: If I not enter in the div that appear the event doesn't execute

Comment: And if I do the same to the father div, I can't put the mouse over the div that appear

Comment: this is doing the same, is not useful

Answer (score 0):

When you select an element, you already have its children.  You can use built in jquery functions like `find()` to perform actions on the element's children.

If you're looking for a specific way to build a generic selector, you can pass jquery a comma separated list of elements you're looking for, just like in CSS.  ie `$("div, p, span, h1, h2")`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `mouseout` use [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/).

Comment: for me is the same mouseout and mouseleave